# How do I find the current machine's full hostname in C (hostname and domain information)?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, environment

In a C project (POSIX), how do I get the fully qualified name for the current system?

For example, I can get just the hostname of my machine by doing
`gethostname()` from unistd.h. This might give me `machine3` in return, but I'm actually looking for `machine3.somedomain.com` for example.

How do I go about getting this information? I do not want to use a call to system() to do this, if possible.

Comment: `gethostname` is the right answer. If you called `system` for `hostname --fqdn` it would simply call `gethostname` under the hood. Your problem is different: `gethostname` isn't returning the "host name" (aka FQDN) because you're not participating in the DNS, possibly because of an issue with `/etc/hosts`. In this case `gethostname` simply returns the "hostname" (no space), which is correctly `machine3`, rather than the FQDN, because you don't have an FQDN.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To get a fully qualified name for a machine, we must first get the local hostname, and then lookup the canonical name.

The easiest way to do this is by first getting the local hostname using `uname()` or `gethostname()` and then performing a lookup with `gethostbyname()` and looking at the `h_name` member of the struct it returns. If you are using ANSI c, you *must* use `uname()` instead of `gethostname()`.

Example:

```
char hostname[1024];
hostname[1023] = '\0';
gethostname(hostname, 1023);
printf("Hostname: %s\n", hostname);
struct hostent* h;
h = gethostbyname(hostname);
printf("h_name: %s\n", h->h_name);
```

Unfortunately, `gethostbyname()` is deprecated in the current POSIX specification, as it doesn't play well with IPv6. A more modern version of this code would use `getaddrinfo()`.

Example:

```
struct addrinfo hints, *info, *p;
int gai_result;

char hostname[1024];
hostname[1023] = '\0';
gethostname(hostname, 1023);

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; /*either IPV4 or IPV6*/
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;

if ((gai_result = getaddrinfo(hostname, "http", &hints, &info)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(gai_result));
    exit(1);
}

for(p = info; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    printf("hostname: %s\n", p->ai_canonname);
}

freeaddrinfo(info);
```

Of course, this will only work if the machine has a FQDN to give - if not, the result of the `getaddrinfo()` ends up being the same as the unqualified hostname.

Comment: I believe you skipped your call to freeaddrinfo() when getaddrinfo() succeeds!

Comment: By the way here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/gethostname.html is said that `Host names are limited to 255 bytes.`. You use 1024.

Comment: @skwllsp: 255 was the limit in SUSv2 (1997); since 2001, the limit is technically HOST_NAME_MAX / sysconf(_SC_HOST_NAME_MAX), which might exceed 255 (the absolute minimum value for _POSIX_HOST_NAME_MAX, #defined in <limits.h>), and in fact might exceed 1023 as well; of course this is just theory; but in practice, 1023 is just as correct as 255 here :^)

Comment: On  an IX'ish box the "hostname" does not need to correlated at all to the result of a DNS query for any of its interfaces' network addresses! The command `hostname` might return `box1` where as the the ip assigned to `eth0` would resolve to return `box2.test2.net` and the one on `eth1` would resolve to return `box3.test3.net`.

Comment: This solution won't work if hostname is set to not map to any FDQN for any interfaces' address.

Answer (score 12):

My solution:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif

void GetMachineName(char machineName[150])
{
    char Name[150];
    int i=0;

    #ifdef WIN32
        TCHAR infoBuf[150];
        DWORD bufCharCount = 150;
        memset(Name, 0, 150);
        if( GetComputerName( infoBuf, &bufCharCount ) )
        {
            for(i=0; i<150; i++)
            {
                Name[i] = infoBuf[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(Name, "Unknown_Host_Name");
        }
    #else
        memset(Name, 0, 150);
        gethostname(Name, 150);
    #endif
    strncpy(machineName,Name, 150);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`gethostname()` is POSIX way to get local host name. Check out `man`.

BSD function `getdomainname()` can give you domain name so you can build fully qualified hostname. There is no POSIX way to get a domain I'm afraid.

Comment: gethostname only returns the local hostname. I'm looking for the fully qualified name.

Comment: `getdomainname` returns the NIS domain name, which may not necessarily match the DNS domain name, or even be set at all

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for:

[gethostbyaddress](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostbyaddr.html)

Just pass it the localhost IP.

There is also a gethostbyname function, that is also usefull.

Comment: if you give it 127.0.0.1 as IP address you are likely to get localhost or localhost.localdomain as answer. It is not common to assign the machines full hostname to a loopback interface.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way, try uname()

If that does not work, use gethostname() then gethostbyname() and finally gethostbyaddr()

The h_name of hostent{} should be your FQDN

Comment: uname gives me the same result as gethostbyname. I haven't tried gethostbyaddr yet.