# How should I get the fully qualified domain name of "localhost" in c++ (on ubuntu)?

Tags: c++, linux, fqdn

I've been messing around with getaddrinfo and getnameinfo but the closest I got to useful output was "localhost.localdomain".  I'm not sure what to pass in for the "node" or "service" args of getaddrinfo, although I think it's the function I want.

Comment: You cannot, with any kind of reliability, convert "localhost" into a fully qualified domain.  There might, for example, be several fully qualified domains which use the same IP address, or there might be none.  If, in your specific case, you *know* there is a unique fully qualified domain, then just specify it in your app via a config file.  In your case, it appears localhost.localdomain IS the fully qualified domain, as configured in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Zxaos's answer here is pretty much the answer I was looking for (even though it's for C and mine was for C++, it works in both):

[How do I find the current machine's full hostname in C (hostname and domain information)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504810/how-do-i-find-the-current-machines-full-hostname-in-c-hostname-and-domain-infor)

So I guess my question was a duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following command:

```
#hostname --fqdn
```

Works well with OpenSuse flavour. Not sure about Ubuntu.