# QT Start program as regular user

Tags: c++, qt

My auto updater requires admin privileges to run since its modifying files in the programs folder. This all works fine.

However, when the update is done I want my `updater.exe` to start `myApplication.exe` but **without** admin privileges.

The code I currently use to start myApplication.exe from updater.exe:

```
bool started = QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(exeFileName));
if (started)
{
    QApplication::quit();
}
```

The problem is that when `myApplication.exe` is started as admin it messes up my local paths, for example:

```
QString addin_path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation);
```

Points to the admin users folder. And not the actual user who is running the application.

Any ideas here?

**update**

Based on Merlin069's answer I'm testing the following:

```
TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &size);

qDebug() << QHostInfo::localHostName();

QProcess::startDetached("runas \"/user:<" + QHostInfo::localHostName() + ">\"" + username + ""\" \"" + exeFileName + "\");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Windows here.

You can launch your application with QProcess::startDetached and use the Windows [RunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx) command line program to run as a different user.

For example: -

```
QProcess::startDetached("runas /user:<localmachinename>\user exeFileName");
```

If the paths contain spaces, surround them in quotes: -

```
QProcess::startDetached("runas \"/user:<localmachinename>\user\" \"exeFileName\"");
```

Comment: How can i find out what user i should run as? and also how do i find out localmachinename?

Comment: You should be able to search for that easily enough with Google. For example, to get the logged in user: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/421tdddx.aspx or the local machine name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504810/how-do-i-find-the-current-machines-full-hostname-in-c-hostname-and-domain-info. Alternatively, using Qt for the hostname: QHostInfo::localHostName().

Comment: Just noticed that the RunAs command requires the user to enter a password

Comment: Can you confirm that? I would expect that would not be the case if coming from an administrator account.

Comment: Yea can confirm, my updater.exe is running as admin but and when the fire the code above I get a cmd prompt asking me to enter the password for my user

Comment: Instead of using runas /user..., does it work if you just specify the trust level? So that would be QProcess::startDetached("runas /TrustLevel:0x20000 exeFileName");

Comment: Just tried, but myApplication.exe still runs as admin that way

Comment: And if you combine TrustLevel and specifying the user, does it still ask for the password?

Comment: Cant seem to combind the two

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51605/discussion-between-merlin069-and-user3490755)