# How to get the hostname using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qtnetwork

How to get the host name of my desktop PC?

Like this, to get system information for Symbian OS:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Get_device_information_using_Qt

Comment: you can simply call system("hostname"); or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504810/how-do-i-find-the-current-machines-full-hostname-in-c-hostname-and-domain-info

Comment: @Velthune: it is a Qt question (from yesterday).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are probably look for this:

> [[static] QString QHostInfo::​localHostName()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhostinfo.html#localHostName)
>
> Returns the host name of this machine.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QHostInfo>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    qDebug() << QHostInfo::localHostName();
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core network
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
"myhostname"
```

Answer (score 2):

you know that class QHostInfo?

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhostinfo.html

```
qDebug(QHostInfo::localHostName().toLocal8Bit());
```