# How to get Fully qualified domain name in unix

Tags: c, unix, networking, c++03, fqdn

Is there any function(C or C++) which returns FQDN(Fully qualified domain name) in UNIX platforms?

Comment: man 3 getnameinfo, example in the man page

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the current machine's full hostname in C (hostname and domain information)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504810/how-do-i-find-the-current-machines-full-hostname-in-c-hostname-and-domain-info)

Answer (score 2):

Use `getifaddrs()` to get the interfaces for the box in question, then use the ["resolver interface" (`man resolver`)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/resolver.3.html) to query the FQDNs for the ip-addresses return by the former call to `getifaddrs()`.

Do not use [`gethostname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html) or the [command line tool `hostname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hostname.1.html) in this context, as an IXish box's "hostname" does not necessarily correlate with the FQDN's returned by a query issued for the box's interface-addresses via the "resolver interface".